# External Stylesheet not loading

Tags: html, css

I've been going through the exercises at https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_responsive . When I do a local test site with that code, and the style copied into a css file, everything loads properly. But when I start to work on my own local site, using almost the same code, the external stylesheet will not load and I do not understand why. I'm coming back to this after a few months away, but I shouldn't be missing anything here.

my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WIP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

<ul class="topnav">
    
    <li> <a href="#menu"> Menu </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#contact"> Contact </a> </li>
    
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

my CSS:

```
body (
    margin: 0;
    }

* { 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
    

/* responsive desktop column layouts */

.col-1 {width: 8.33%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-3 {width: 25%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-6 {width: 50%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-9 {width: 75%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}
.col-12 {width: 100%; float: left; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;}



/*The columns inside a row are all floating to the left, and are therefore taken out of the flow of the page, 
and other elements will be placed as if the columns do not exist. To prevent this, we will add a style that clears the flow:*/
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* FONTS */
@font-face {
    font-family: Italiana-Regular;
    src: url('fonts/Italiana-Regular.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Italianno-Regular;
    src: url('fonts/Italianno-Regular.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: VesperLibre-Regular;
    src: url('fonts/VesperLibre-Regular.ttf');
    
}


/* nav */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(195,38,45);
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a local server for development? I believe that just opening the HTML file from the filesystem into the browser will prevent assets from loading as path would be to your disk directly. Also, what is the error in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index.css file has two typos.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* --snip-- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* --snip-- */
```

I recommend using an editor like VSCode to catch these errors.

Comment: this was it. the ( instead of the { and forgetting the second }. that's what I get for typing while tired after work. thank you very much!